# Subquery Getting Slower as Rentals grows

Tags: sql-server

I have a subquery that is exetremly slower as rental grows and I am wondering id there is a solution to write a subquery that is faster. NULL is not indexed

```
SELECT ALBUMId, ALBUMTitle 
FROM ALBUM
WHERE ALBUMId IN(SELECT ALBUMId FROM RENTAL
WHERE RntalReturnedDate IS NULL);
```

No indexes are created.
what are your thoughts.

Comment: My first thoughts are: why are there no indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ALBUMId, a.ALBUMTitle
    FROM ALBUM a
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM RENTAL r
                     WHERE a.ALBUMId = r.ALBUMId
                         AND r.RntalReturnedDate IS NULL);
```